# How to remove elements from can.List in CanJS

Tags: canjs, canjs-list

I'm new to CanJS. I was wondering how to remove the elements in can.List not using pop().

```
var todos1=new can.List([
              {name: "Apple",selected: false},
              {name: "Ball",selected: true},
              {name: "Cat",selected: false}                
            ]);
```

How to remove an element in the list with selected=true? Or is there any way to delete according to index. Documentation tells pop() is the only way and also splice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use [splice](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.prototype.splice.html) or [filter](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.prototype.filter.html) the list by the selected attribute and then [replace](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.prototype.replace.html) it:

```
var todos1=new can.List([
  {name: "Apple",selected: false},
  {name: "Ball",selected: true},
  {name: "Cat",selected: false}                
]);

todos1.replace(todos1.filter(function(todo) {
  return todo.attr('selected') === true;
}));
```

Now `todos1` will only contain the selected elements.